# Change public hostname of my ISP

Tags: networking

When I connect to a VPN (whatever it's a free or a paid one), I have for example "poney telecom" or another fictitious name, so how do they do it ? It I wanna do it in my server at home and my internet connection, how to do it ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What *public hostname*? Do you mean the reverse DNS entry of your public IP address?

Comment: Yes, I  mean the reverse DNS entry of my public IP address

Comment: Your DNS is probably `customer9437.outinthesticksnode752.yourISP.com`. You are not in charge of that.

Comment: So... How VPN change it ?

Comment: They become your 'last point' before the open interwebz. You can't change that, in the same way you can't change your ISP's. It's not yours to change.

Comment: what do you mean by "They become your 'last point' " ?

Comment: Same as your router before you invoke a VPN, It's your point of entry into the wider world. Prior to that you've been in an equivalent of an 'internal network'… that's the whole idea of a VPN in the way people use them these days for 'anonimity' - to move your 'point of origin'.

Answer (score 1):

When you connect to a VPN you are using your Internet connection to make a second, encrypted connection to another provider—but instead of using a physical or wifi connection as the way to deliver it, you use the existing Internet connection.

The takeaways are:

- You can't arbitrarily change your IP/reverse IP address.
- Your VPN provider has acquired resources and is acting like an ISP. As a corollary, your traffic through the VPN can be tracked to the VPN provider—which is why people looking at VPN providers care about their logging and payment policies.

**To change the domain name associated with an IP address you need to control its DNS—and this needs to be delegated to you from your provider or set on your behalf by the controlling ISP. Many residential providers won't do this. If this is what you are asking about, reverse DNS delegation is a special DNS name "in-addr.arpa" with special subdomains delegated to separate servers and eventually resolving to a PTR record type.  This has nothing to do with a VPN or  provider**

Answer (score 1):

Only the IP owner can change reverse DNS entries. The IP owner is your ISP. Usually, they'd require you to have a business plan (or any plan with a static IP address) before allowing changes to the reverse DNS entry for your IP address.

When connecting to a VPN, you appear on the net with a different IP address. This time, it is owned by the VPN provider (or their ISP). They may have their reverse DNS entries changed to some witty value.

---

You can find out who "owns" an IP address using a WHOIS lookup tool. The owner will have the relevant special `.in-addr.arpa` subdomain delegated to them.